# Finding the elastic limit by graph

Tags: homework-and-exercises, elasticity

[image: Question 22]

I always thought that the elastic limit is at an exact point for a force extension graph. I do not understand why the elastc limit is beyond point S. I also know that the elastic limit means the max force a wire can handle allowing it to return to its original shape.

Comment: A guess:  It looks like the graph stays linear for a short while just beyond point S.

Answer (score 0):

There's a subtle difference between elastic limit and what is called the **limit of proportionality** the limit of proportionality is when the graph becomes non linear ( deviates from a straight line / curves) but elastic limit is the point after which when the load is removed the spring does not come back to its original length. So here that point should lie just after S ( as at T it's already far from elastic limit as when the load is removed it's far from original length but just after S there will be a point where after removing load the spring will be just a bit longer than original length)
Answer should be B

Comment: I wonder if there is an obvious reason why the elastic limit has to be after the proportionality limit

Comment: It seems to be just the mathematical concept, like linearity loss does not necessarily mean that elasticity is lost hence the elastic limit comes after ( like even non linear deformation can be elastic due to specific interactions in molecules )

Comment: It is not a mathematical concept: why can't the elastic limit happen before the proportionality limit is reached? Why does linearity has to be lost first?

Comment: Might have to do with elastic bond interactions where they are linear until when the proportionality is reached then some of the bond breaks and the interactions need less and less force but can still get back to original position. Then after elastic limit the bond breaking has an irreversible effect.

Comment: @WillyBillyWilliams After you pass the elastic limit, some something *irreversible* has happened to the material. It's hard to imagine how that could happen at the molecular or atomic level and the slope of the stress-strain curve *not*  changing. But for very elastic materials, whether you get a "straight" or "curved" stress-strain plot depends what measure of stress and strain you use - for example engineer's stress and strain are based on the undeformed shape of the material, but true stress and logarithmic strain are based on the deformed shape as it changes when the load is applied.